# Graph edit on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, directshow, graphedit

I'm not able to find graphedit tool on windows 10 64 bit m/c, I have also installed the windows 10 sdk as per microsoft docs.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/using-graphedit

Could anyone advice me on the links for instructions and download for getting the latest version of graph-edit and any pre-requisite steps to get it working on windows 10.

Regards,

Arjun

Answer (score 9):

GraphEdit is available from Windows SDK, typical paths are:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\<x.x.x.x>\x86\graphedt.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\<x.x.x.x>\x64\graphedt.exe
```

`<x.x.x.x>` is a version number.

Answer (score 6):

In my Windows 10 Home it was in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86`

It is **not** where MSDN says it is. (version number: `10.0.18362.0` may of course differ)

Answer (score 1):

Another location: `D:\Windows Kits\10\bin\<version>\x64\graphedt.exe`

Drive D may come from me installing VisualStudio2017 on D:\sw\dev\VisualStudio2017\ and installing the Windows SDK from VS2017's installer at a later time (there's an "alter" button).

But how the installer comes up with creating a new directory in D's root is beyond me.